# How do I recover the name of a downloaded artifact in a deployment job of Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm building a multi-stage pipeline in which my build stage stores a single file as a pipeline artifact. In the deployment stage the artifact is automatically download and I need the name of the file in order to proceed with the following steps.

Currently, I'm publishing as a variable the name of the file stored as the artifact of the build. I'm wondering if the `download` task would be able to provide the name of the file so that I can further decouple the build and deploy stages.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
    - bash: |
        jarFile=`ls -1 *.jar`
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jarFile;isOutput=true]${jarFile}"
      workingDirectory: target
      name: mavenTarget
      displayName: Finds name of built `.jar` file
```

And then in the deployment stage:

```
variables:
    - name: jarFile
      value: $[ stageDependencies.ci.build.outputs['mavenTarget.jarFile'] ]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details, does your code work? if not, what is the symptome ? At least, it seems that the syntax is good as per [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops), it would be nice if you can provide the full code without sensitive information of course.

Comment: The code I posted works, I'm just wondering if I'm overcomplicating things since a few pipeline tasks already set useful output variables. `DownloadSecureFile` exports a `secureFile` property, for example. If `download` gave me the name of the downloaded artifact I could eliminate a dependence between stages.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if the download task would be able to provide the name of the file so that I can further decouple the build and deploy stages.

I am afraid that the Download build artifacts task has no built-in output variable that can represent the name of an artifact or the files in the Artifact.

The output variable of the download artifacts task is `XXX.buildnumber`. It doesn't contain the info about Artifacts Name or the files in Artifacts.

[image]

The [cross-stage variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage) used in your Current YAML is an efficient way. You can continue to use the method.